# Is there a citeable reference for star-shaped open subsets of R^n being diffeomorphic to R^n?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

A folk theorem says that star-shaped open subsets of R^n are diffeomorphic to R^n.

Is there a citeable reference for a proof of this result?
For the sake of being definite, let's say that
“citeable” means indexed by Mathematical Reviews or Zentralblatt,
or available on arXiv.

The answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/4516 gives two references for this theorem, neither of which is citeable in the above sense: online notes and an obscure book, impossible to locate.  There are many citeable sources that state this result without a proof.

Comment: Why doesn't someone write a short note, stick it on the arXiv? And then get it published in one of _American Mathematical Monthly_, _Expositiones Mathematicae_ (Elsevier, though!), _Confluentes Mathematici_ etc (sourced from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work). Also, some relevant discussion/references is in http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ball

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Good suggestion, although the note might not be as short as one might expect it to be: the proof in online notes occupies 3 pages.

Comment: all the better, since a one-pager might be considered too trifling. From my perspective, a proof that includes the relevant material on existence of good open covers for manifolds would be best (if one but had time for such a thing). The road to that proof goes via estimates on convexity radii coming from estimates on curvature, going back to old work of Whitehead, and which could do with a modern interpretation.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Actually I was discussing the existence of differentiable good open covers with Urs Schreiber when he visited Göttingen, and the result of the discussion was that one doesn't need any curvature or convexity radius estimates.  Here's the proposed proof: to construct a differentiable good open cover of a smooth manifold use partitions of unity to construct a Riemannian metric and take the set of all geodesically convex subsets.  They are closed under intersection and the inverse of the geodesic flow transforms any geodesically convex open set into a star-shaped open set.  QED

Comment: Are there any issues with convexity radii not being bounded away from zero on a non-compact manifold? In any case, perhaps this short argument would make the case for including the proof in a note explaining the original question even stronger...

Comment: Ah, existence of geodesically convex neighbourhoods for any point can be found in eg do Carmo _Riemannian geometry_, Proposition 4.2. Cool! I hope "someone" writes this note up. ;-)

Comment: I wound up down this same rabbit hole while writing my book (still in progress). If a $C^1$ version starting with convex sets (rather than star-shaped) is good enough for you, the reference I'm using for that is:  M. Gromov, Convex sets and Kähler manifolds, Advances in differential geometry and topology, World Sci. Publ., Teaneck, NJ, 1990, pp. 1–38, Section, I.4.C1

Comment: @GregFriedman: Yes, I am aware of Gromov's proof, but sometimes a C^∞-diffeomorphism is needed, e.g., to construct differentiable good open covers on a C^∞-manifold, which is the application that I had in mind when posting this question.  (Does it make sense to include a proof for the C^∞-case in your book?  A lot of people would be grateful if you did this…)

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Hmm, I'm not sure I know how to prove this from scratch, but maybe I can incorporate the Born/Ferus proof in an appendix. Of course better would be convincing Born to publish it as a paper, and that way it would be more thoroughly refereed. Has anyone asked him to do this?

Comment: @GregFriedman: No, as far as I am aware, nobody tried to contact them.  Georges Elencwajg claims in the answer that I link to in my post that Gonnord and Tosel also have a proof in their book (http://www.worldcat.org/title/calcul-differentiel/oclc/40241391), apparently simpler than that of Born's, but I was unable to locate the book, although a paper copy seems to be present in my city library.

Comment: I also tried to get ahold of that book through interlibrary loan, but the library didn't manage to get it for me. Maybe we can get someone to e-mail us a scan of the proof.

Comment: @GregFriedman: Meanwhile I wrote up an easier proof that came up in a lunch discussion: http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/1947/ball/?Focus=52585#Comment_52585

Comment: @GregFriedman have a look at this more recent answer (http://mathoverflow.net/a/212595/11211) to the MO question linked by the OP with a link to a manuscript copy done by Erwann Aubry. In any case, I managed to buy a used copy of the book "Calcul Différentiel"  by Gonnord and Tosel, and the proof there is indeed much neater than the one in Dirk Ferus's lecture notes. Unfortunately, they provide no references for it, which is a bit strange (for they do so for other results in the book) and also begs the question of whether this proof is actually due to the authors themselves or not...

Comment: @DavidRoberts the theorem of existence of geodesically convex neighborhoods is due to J.H.C. Whitehead (*Convex Regions in the Geometry of Paths*, Quart. J. Math. **3** (1932) 33-42). A proof valid for any manifold with an affine connection (not just Riemannian) may be found in the charming (although unfortunately out-of-print) little book of Noel J. Hicks (the same from the Cartan-Ambrose-Hicks theorem), *Notes on Differential Geometry* (Van Nostrand, 1965), Section 9.4, pp. 134-136.

Comment: The books by Hicks is available here: http://libgen.io/book/index.php?md5=FDE69DDB5FB0E16D44FD9CA73E10C8C0

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro thanks! I knew about the Whitehead reference, but it's pretty hard and buried in the midst of many other things.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: I was curious to find the proof that you have written on MathForge, but I got "Error 1001: DNS resolution error" from Cloudfare (which seems to host the domain). There is no copy of the page on the WayBack Machine either. Please consider posting it on a more stable site.

Comment: @AlexM.: nForum moved, mathforge should be replaced with ncatlab (it is quite stable).  The new link is https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/1947/ball/?Focus=52585#Comment_52585.  See also this proof:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb/212595#212595.  An elegant proof of the existence of good open covers was given by Demailly: https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/1947/ball/?Focus=67203#Comment_67203.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Why don't you add your proof to https://mathoverflow.net/q/4468? It would fit naturally in that discussion, and would also get significantly more visibility (and would spare the readers the pain of hunting for it on the internet).

Comment: @AlexM.: My old proof on the nForum is essentially the proof of Gonnord and Tosel explained in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb/212595#212595, except that they make additional simplifications.

Comment: @AlexM.: The proof is also present as Theorem 2.6 in the nLab article "ball": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ball

Comment: I gave this as a (hard) homework problem this semester in a graduate-level course Intro to Smooth Manifolds. One student came up with a really good proof.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie: Is the proof similar to the one presented in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbr/212595#212595?  If not, it may be beneficial to post it there.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: Yes, it's similar to that one.

Comment: After seven years I propose the answer is "no".

Answer (score 6):

The result in the following paper implies that open star-shaped domainin $\mathbb{R}^n$ is *homeomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
But, in your case, a diffeomorphism can be obtained along the same lines.

K. W. Kwun. “Uniqueness of the open cone neighborhood”. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.
15 (1964), pp. 476–479.

**Postscript.** Instead of a reference one could write the following lines:

Any star-shaped open set $\Omega$ is a union of a nested sequence of star-shaped open regions $\Omega_0\subset \Omega_1\subset\dots$ such that $\partial\Omega_n$ is a graph of a smooth Lipschitz function in the polar coordinates. We can assume that $\Omega_0$ is a disc; in particular $\Omega_0$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Observe that for each $n$ there is a diffeomorphism $\phi_n\colon\bar \Omega_{n-1}\to\bar\Omega_n$; moreover we can assume that $\phi_n$ fix all points away from a tiny neightborhood of $\partial\Omega_n$. In particular, it can be arranged that for any $x_0\in \Omega_0$, the sequence defined by $x_n=\phi_n(x_{n-1})$ stabilizes after finitely many steps. Define $f(x_0)=x_n$ for all large $n$, and observe that $f\colon \Omega_0\to\Omega$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Kwun's proof heavily uses gluing of piecewise continuous maps along closed subsets.  Such constructions cannot be adapted to the setting of diffeomorphisms without considerable modifications, e.g., using smooth bump functions.  While this probably can be done, it would require one to write a proof that is longer than the one presented in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbr/212595#212595, which defeats the very purpose of citing a result instead of writing it up.

Comment: However, for $n\neq 4$ homeomorphism implies diffeomorphism :)

Answer (score 4):

This result is stated as Exercise 7 in Chapter 8 of Bröcker and Jänich's book Introduction to Differential Topology (p. 86 of the English translation). This may or may not count as a citeable reference.

Comment: (It's certainly citeable. But one might hope for a published proof rather than just a brief indication of how a proof might go.)

Comment: I meant a citeable reference with a proof, since there are many known citeable sources that state the result without a proof, e.g., the Bott–Tu book states it, and several others.

Comment: Fair enough. My recollection, from graduate school, was that someone pointed me to this reference saying that it was the closest thing to a proof in the literature.